# Scale Viewport Without Meta Tag

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am currently setting up a responsive page in a wyswyg editor hosted on 1shoppingcart. I cannot set the viewport scale as the meta tags are predefined. Is there a way to implement the following setting with css? JavaScript is also not supported. `content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"`

Answer (score 0):

No. CSS has no equivalent of meta viewport.